# Powershell script reading from a data table errors when it finds a fullstop in value

Tags: sql, powershell

I have adapted a Powershell script that reads the disk space from a series of servers  in my estate.  the issue I am having is some the server names have full stops 'ServerA.A.A' and when Powershell returns the value to get the data from that server, it says

> Invoke-Sqlcmd : Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or
>   SUBSTRING function. The statement has been terminated.

I have tried adding single and double quotes around the name of the server, but it reads it as '"ServerA.A.A", and not ServerA.A.A

How can I add either single or double quotes around the server name, but have PS read it without so these can be read?

EDIT:- I have added the full code below, sorry for not doing this sooner, have used this many times for looking up answers to q's but not posted myself for a long time.

```
   $server = "XXX"
$inventoryDB = "XXXX"

#Create the DiskSpace Table if it doesn't exist in your centralized instance 
#You can remove the 'Monitoring' schema if you want.
$diskSpaceTableCreationQuery = "
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE name = 'DiskSpace' AND xtype = 'U')
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DiskSpace](
   [Instance] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
   [DBName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
   [PhysicalFileLocation] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
   [Drive] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
   [DBFileSizeMB] [int] NULL,
   [TotalSpaceInMB] [int] NULL,
   [FreeSpaceInMB] [int] NULL,
   [PercentFreeSpace] [float] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
"
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $diskSpaceTableCreationQuery -Database $inventoryDB -ServerInstance $server

#Clean the DiskSpace table
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.DiskSpace" -Database $inventoryDB -ServerInstance $server

#Create the thresholds Table if it doesn't exist in your centralized instance
$thresholdsTableCreationQuery = " 
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE name = 'thresholds' AND xtype = 'U')
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[thresholds](
   [id] [tinyint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
   [item] [varchar](25) NOT NULL,
   [warning_value] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
   [critical_value] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_thresholds] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
   [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
"
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $thresholdsTableCreationQuery -Database $inventoryDB -ServerInstance $server

#Insert the threshold value to set the upper cap that the SP will use to limit the result set (the value won't be inserted if it already exists.
#This is designed this way so that you can use this table to store threshold values for other purposes (CPU, RAM, etc.)
$thresholdValueInsertQuery = "
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT item FROM dbo.thresholds 
               WHERE item = 'disk_space')
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO dbo.thresholds VALUES ('disk_space', 50)
END
"
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $thresholdvalueInsertQuery -Database $inventoryDB -ServerInstance $server

#Fetch all the instances with the respective SQL Server Version
<#
   This is an example of the result set that your query must return
   ##################################################
   # name                     # instance            #
   ##################################################
   # server1.domain.net,45000 # server1             #
   # server1.domain.net,45001 # server1\MSSQLSERVER1#
   # server2.domain.net,45000 # server2             #
   # server3.domain.net,45000 # server3             #
   # server4.domain.net       # server4\MSSQLSERVER2#
   ################################################## 
#>

#If you don't have such table in your environment, the following block of code will create it for you. You just simply have to make sure to populate it accordingly.
$instancesTableCreationQuery = "
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE name = 'instances' AND xtype = 'U')
CREATE TABLE instances(
   [name] [nvarchar](128) NULL,
   [instance] [nvarchar](128) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
"
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $instancesTableCreationQuery -Database $inventoryDB -ServerInstance $server

$instanceLookupQuery = "SELECT name, instance FROM instances"

$instances = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $server -Database $inventoryDB -Query $instanceLookupQuery

#For each instance, grab the disk space information
foreach ($instance in $instances){
   $diskSpaceQuery = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $server -Database $inventoryDB -Query "EXEC dbo.disk_space" -MaxCharLength 8000

   #Go grab the disks information for the instance
   Write-Host "Fetching Disk information for instance" $instance.instance
    $results = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $diskSpaceQuery.tsql -ServerInstance $instance.name -ErrorAction Stop -querytimeout 30

   #Perform the INSERT in the DiskSpace table only if it returned at least 1 row
   if($results.Length -ne 0){
      #Build the insert statement
      $insert = "INSERT INTO dbo.DiskSpace VALUES"
      foreach($result in $results){
         $insert += "
         (
         '"+$result.Instance+"',
         '"+$result.DBName+"',
         '"+$result.PhysicalFileLocation+"',
         '"+$result.Drive+"',
         "+$result.DBFileSizeMB+",
         "+$result.TotalSpaceInMB+",
         "+$result.FreeSpaceInMB+",
         "+$result.PercentFreeSpace+"
         ),
         "
      }

      #Store the results in the local DiskSpace table in your central instance
      Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $insert.Substring(0,$insert.LastIndexOf(',')) -ServerInstance $server -Database $inventoryDB
   } 
}
Write-Host "Done!"
```

Comment: Do you have an outer single quote pair that encompasses the double quotes? If you are passing the server name into the `-ServerInstance` parameter, you could just store the server name in a variable first and then use the variable there: `-ServerInstance $servername`.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure I know what you mean. here is the code that I think is faiking.  <br/>    $instanceLookupQuery = "SELECT name, instance FROM instances"
 
$instances = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $server -Database $inventoryDB -Query $instanceLookupQuery
 
#For each instance, grab the disk space information</code>
foreach ($instance in $instances){
   $diskSpaceQuery = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $server -Database $inventoryDB -Query "EXEC dbo.disk_space" -MaxCharLength 8000 [/code]

Comment: Can you post the code where `$server` is set? It is easier for everyone if the code is posted in the question rather than the comments. It is very helpful to post relevant code with any question.

Comment: Sorry, I have added this full code into the original post.

Comment: You haven't included the failing `SUBSTRING` or `LEFT` SQL statement which is probably in the `dbo.disk_space` stored proc.  
Also, `$insert` will not be valid SQL if there is more than one result. You will have to repeat the `INSERT INTO dbo.DiskSpace VALUES ` string for each set of values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem lies in PowerShell's variable expansion in your last `Invoke-Sqlcmd` call.

What PowerShell is probably doing is instead of passing the result of `$insert.Substring(0,$insert.LastIndexOf(','))`, it's literally passing `<value of $insert>.Substring(0,$insert.LastIndexOf(','))`

Although I can't test this, I think this is your problem because of the error message provided:

> Invoke-Sqlcmd : Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or **SUBSTRING** function. The statement has been terminated

This is an SQL error and there's nowhere in your code where you use the SQL `SUBSTRING()` function.

To fix this, use a [Subexpression Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-5.1#special-operators):

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $($insert.Substring(0,$insert.LastIndexOf(','))) -ServerInstance $server -Database $inventoryDB
```

The `$( )` ensures that the result of an expression is what's passed to the `-Query` Parameter.

Comment: Thank you Mason, this has things working now, very much appreciated, I have upvoted this, but it is not showing as I do not have enough rep ;-(